# How to tell if a Zigbee device is a Zigbee Router

Tags: zigbee, mesh-networks

The Zigbee spec defines the types of nodes: [coordinators, routers, and end devices.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zigbee#Device_types_and_operating_modes) I'm looking to buy some Zigbee devices, but I can't find in the device manual if the device is a Zigbee Router or an end device. Example [device manual](https://byjasco.com/mwdownloads/download/link/id/1270/)

How can I tell if a Zigbee device is a Zigbee Router? Can you provide an example of a device which is labeled as a Zigbee router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if it is connected to mains power, it’s a router, whereas if it is battery-powered it’s an end device. Not sure this is 100% true, but probably very close to it.

[This page](https://github.com/dresden-elektronik/deconz-rest-plugin/issues/1058) shows it is an FFD (full function device), so it can act as a router.